# href link contain base url in laravel 5

Tags: html, href

I'm trying to get url link form database in laravel5 like that.

```
<p class="title">{{$promotion->link}}</p>
<a href="{{$promotion->link}}" target="_blank" 
class="label label-info pull-right">View Link</a>
```

> $promotion->link = "www.google.com";

Result >>

```
1.www.google.com
2.<a href="localhost/www.google.com".....
```

I don't know why the link in  contain base url "localhost" . I can't redirect the link with url in my website. Please help and show me the right way.

Thanks and respect to all geek!!!

Comment: Does removing `target="_blank"` fix your issue?

Comment: Nope , I think it doesn't depend with that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <a href="/{{$promotion->link}}" target="_blank" class="label label-info pull-right">View Link</a>
```

Comment: @Ram he added a `/` to change the link from a relative link to an absolute link

Comment: @Craicerjack I was reviewing it in low quality review queue and added this comments as a part of the review so that it doesn't wind up as a low quality post in the review again.

Comment: Adding double slash worked for me. like this <a href="//{{$promotion->link}}" >

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look:

```
<a href="{{link($promotion->link)}}" target="_blank" class="label label-info pull-right">View Link</a>
```